# Angular - Reference a library to another in same application

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I'm developing a tool set to be used in out organization. I'v created an Angular library (let's call it) `core` so I wanna to create another library using `ng g library` in the same project which needs to reference to `core`.

Project structure:

- Libraries (created by `ng new`)

  - **Core** (created by `ng g library Core`)
  - **Pack1** (created by `ng g library Pack1`). I want to this package be able to use **Core**.
- Application (created by `ng new`)

  - needs to use **Pack1**.

I'm at the beginning of the **Pack1** creation. how should I reference to **Core** from **Pack1**?

also I would like to use `npm link`, because I'm just developing parts.

#### UPDATE:

I tried to publish **Core** with `npm publish` and refer to `@myOrg/core` in **Pack1**, but then I've to run `npm i @myOrg/core` in **Libraries** project to be able to reference it in **Pack1**.

If so, when running `ng build Pack1` the following error is genereted:

```
BUILD ERROR
: Can't resolve all parameters for ɵb in B:/0. Projects/dashboard/lib-shared/node_modules/@myOrg/core/core.d.ts: (?, [object Object], [object Object]).
```

because of circular referencing.

Comment: So... what's stopping you?

Comment: I updated the question, sorry, I just was in a hurry

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?